# Show div on hover of embeded div

Tags: css

I'm trying to display div.overlay on hover of embedded div.box

```
div.overlay {padding:5px; background:#F00; width:100px; visibility: hidden;}
div.box {display:block; background:#FF0; width:100px; visibility:visible;}
div.box:hover div.overlay { visibility: visible;}

<div class="overlay">
<div class="box">Info about a game</div>
Play
</div>
```

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Are you planning to use jQuery?

Comment: How are you expecting to hover over something that isn't visible?

Comment: you (still) can not dictate behaviour from chidren to parents in css

Comment: Similar question (which I answered, admittedly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563482/ikea-style-lightbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hover on the parent element and that seems to make it work e.g:

```css
div.overlay:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52sM5/

Comment: Great! Thanks Flame Trap. That exactly what I missed :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you change the markup slightly if possible. It will make it possible to do what you want.

**Option 1:**

HTML

```
<div class="box">Info about a game</div>
<div class="overlay">Play</div>
```

CSS

```
div.box,
div.overlay {
  width: 100px; 
  background: #FF0; }

div.overlay { display: none; }

div.box:hover + div.overlay { display: block; }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uM49/

**Option 2**

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    Info about a game
    <div class="overlay">Play</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.box {
  width: 100px; 
  background: #FF0; }

div.overlay { display: none; }

div.box:hover div.overlay { display: block; }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgXDT/

Comment: Thanks Coop, but I need to show border with padding around the embedded div on hover.

Comment: So just use my option 2 and add padding to div.box. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/kgXDT/1/

Comment: Option 2 is a little better, because you can keep the mouse over `overlay` without hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

copy and replace your css with my css

```
div.overlay {padding:5px; background:#F00; width:100px; visibility: hidden;}
div.box {display:block; background:#FF0; width:100px; visibility:visible;}
div.overlay:hover { visibility: visible;}
```